# How to Get Nesting from List of Rows

Tags: powershell, nested

I have data like this :

```
StartTime   GroupName   Process
12:00:00    Group1      Start
12:01:00    Group1      End
12:01:00    Group2      Start
12:01:00    Group3      Start
12:05:00    Group3      End
12:05:00    Group2      End
```

I need to establish how long each Group ran for (which is easy and I have done) but I also want to establish how the groups are nested. Ideally I want an output like this :

```
GroupName   ParentGroup Start       End         DurationMinutes
Group1      root        12:00:00    12:01:00    1
Group2      root        12:01:00    12:05:00    4
Group3      Group2      12:01:00    12:05:00    4
```

Using this code, I have managed to get close, but I am struggling with how to get the nesting. In my example there is only 1 level but it could be n levels in reality.

```
$groupoutput = @()
foreach ($line in $hash)
{
    $thisgroupname = $line.GroupName
    if($line.Process -eq Start)
    {
        ## Start of Group
        $obj = [pscustomobject]@{
            GroupName = $line.GroupName
            ParentGroup = $null
            StartTime = $line.ExecutionTime
            EndTime = $null
            Duration = $null
            DurationSeconds = $null
        }
        $groupoutput += $obj
    } elseif ($line.Process -eq End)
    {
        ## End of Group
        $findgroup = $groupoutput | ?{$_.GroupName -eq $line.GroupName}
        $findgroup.EndTime = $line.ExecutionTime
    }
}

## Calculate Duration of Each Group
$groupoutput | % {$_.Duration = $_.EndTime - $_.StartTime}

## Calculate Duration in Seconds
$groupoutput | % {$_.DurationSeconds = $_.Duration.TotalSeconds}
#endregion
```

Do I need a recursive function?

Comment: What in that data tells you what the parent group is? Is it because a group has a start process before some other group has an end process?

Comment: Yes, the start and end define if the group is nested. If a group starts and doesn't end before another group starts, then the second group is nested within the first group.

Comment: So just have avariable that gets set whenever a start event happens. If a start event happens and it is not null then that is the parent for that group. Whenever an end event happens then set it to that group's parent.

Comment: @EBGreen Wow, I was really over thinking this, I just tried it and it works! Can you post your answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a holder variable that you initialize to $null. Then whenever a Start process occurs, the parent for that group is the value in the holder variable and the holder variable is changed to hold the name of that group. Whenever an End process occurs, the holder variable is set to the value of the parent for the group that is ending.